# Cannot redirect page in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

So I'm trying to redirect to a page in EJS, it doesn't work, for some reason. My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/public/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>PRIVATE FOR SECURITY REASONS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <label for="username">Enter Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        <label for="password">Enter Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <form action="/validate" method=POST>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

when I type all the things in and click submit, it doesn't redirect me to /validate. /validate's code is here:

```js
app.post("/validate", function (req, res) {
    res.render("validate")
})
```

ejs is this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="/public/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>PRIVATE FOR SECURITY REASONS</title>
</head>

<body>
    <% if (locals.username=="PRIVATE FOR SECURITY REASONS" && locals.password=="PASSWORD" ) { %>
        <% window.location.replace("/" + app.locals.randomhex) %>
            <% } %>
</body>

</html>

the randomhex is here:
app.locals.randomhex = [...Array(16)].map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16)).join('');
```

and should i just screw all of this garbage and use passport instead? (im trying to learn things without fancy pants npm stuff)

Comment: Why redirect from a redirect?  Your server should just decide what the final URL should be before the first redirect and then redirect to that final URL.  If you're trying to do some sort of random redirect, then just put that logic into the `/validate` route where you do the first redirect.

Comment: So you're saying that instead of doing another redirect to /validate, I should just skip that and just let it go to /my/113fad75491debc6 or something?

Comment: Redirect it once to whatever the final destination is.  Multiple redirects are inefficient and pointless in this case since you have server-side code already that can calculate what you want the final destination to be.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN'T redirect pages in EJS, because EJS is SERVER-SIDE. You have 2 options for redirects.

If you're using Express.js (other frameworks should be similar), you can redirect in Node with:

```js
res.redirect('/myPage');
```

This example in action:

```js
app.get('/validate', (req, res) => {
   if(req.locals.username=="PRIVATE FOR SECURITY REASONS" && req.locals.password=="PASSWORD" ) {
      res.redirect('/' + app.locals.randomhex);
   } else {
      res.render('validate');
   }
});
```

If you want to check credentials in the EJS (not a very great idea), there is one not so good option/workaround:

```html
<% if (locals.username=="PRIVATE FOR SECURITY REASONS" && locals.password=="PASSWORD" ) { %>
<script>
   window.location.replace("/<%= app.locals.randomhex %>");
</script>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Alright. But the thing I'm trying to do is, when they submit the login form, it will redirect them to a page. How can I do that? Or should I just use passport and screw this nonsense.

Comment: I don't know Passport very well, but the way I approach logins would be using JWT. On the login page, the user sends an AJAX request with his password and email to check. If the server deems it correct, it will put a cookie (best httpOnly) on the user's browser with a JWT, and if the user receives a message that it is correct, the client side tries to redirect. Whenever a user tries to access a page that needs auth, the server checks the user's cookie, and verifies the JWT. If the JWT is verified, the user is allowed to the page; otherwise, he is redirected to the login page.

Comment: I've tried it. But the site throws an error and says that cannot read property of "username" which is undefined.  How do I put something in req.locals? This is the form: `<form action="/validate" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Enter Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        <label for="password">Enter Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        <button>Login</button>
    </form>` (if you dont want to go back to the top)

Comment: Don't use locals. Use (encrypted) cookies or sessions.